# Alfresco 4.2.2 enterprise version to 5.x version

Tags: alfresco

We need to upgrade from Alfresco 4.2.2 enterprise version to 5.1 version.Do we need to go for incremental upgrades or can we do direct upgrade?
Could you please let us know the correct steps to be followed for this up gradation right from checking pre requisites till make the application running with the database dump of existing version (We are using ORACLE 11g database)

Comment: May this help http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/upgrade-process.html

Answer (score 3):

I don't have all the steps, but I do know you can go with direct upgrade. Note the SOLR part of the deal.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/upgrade-path.html

Comment: what do you mean by SOLR part of the deal?

Comment: I mean if you're on Lucene, you need to take care because 5.0 defaults to SOLR.

Comment: As enterprise customer make use of the support. They will be able to answer all your questions.

Comment: It's not that 5.0 defaults to Solr, I believe in 5.0 Lucene is GONE. So if you need transactional support in your code, you should look into migrating to TMQ first (if you are using the repo programatically).

Comment: You're right, this is another "big" thing to care about, SOLR has eventual consistency that can be avoided, but only for some queries. http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/intrans-metadata-query.html